# Is there a serializer to process Objects passed to query string as Arrays?

Tags: javascript, http, axios

Is there a serializer (bundled with Axios or on npm) that can process Object passed to query string from Object to Array?

So that I can send some multidimensional Object as query string params:

```js
let params = {
  'offset': 0,
  'limit': 10,
  'sort': null,
  'contact': {
    'firstname': 'John',
    'lastname': 'Doe',
  },
}
```

and get the final request as:

> {{...ENDPOINT...}}?offset=0&limit=10&contact[firstname]=John&contact[lastname]=Doe

Instead, with default Axios serializer, the final URL request looks like this:

> {{...ENDPOINT...}}?offset=0&limit=10&contact=%7B%22firstname%22:%22John%22,%22lastname%22:%22Doe%22%7D

which is basically just encoded:

> ?offset=0&limit=10&contact={"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe"}